# Convergence of sequences of periodic functions

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Given $f_n(x) = F(x) (\cos(\pi x))^n$, where $n \in \mathbb N , F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ integrable.

Simple question: does the Lebesgue integral converge in $\mathbb R$? (and how to show?)

Answer (score 0):

Does $\cos^n x$ converge? (Yes). Find its limit and apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Yes, $\cos^n (x) $ converges to $-1$. But how can I apply the dominated conv. theorem? I mean i have to find a function g s.t. $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$, right?

Comment: It doesn't actually. Cosine takes values between -1 and 1. Most places (almost everywhere) it is less than 1 in absolute value. Now takes powers...

Comment: Ok, also with powers, the maximum value is always less or equal than 1.  But how can I apply the theorem, in that case?

Comment: If $|a|<1$ then $a^n \rightarrow 0$. Can you see what the (a.e.) pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ is?

Comment: Ok, so if I'm not wrong, then the pointwise limit is 0, right?